# How can I get more useful information from NSError?

Tags: ios, nserror

I want to get some useful information from `NSError`.
If I print out `[error userInfo]`, I get the following:

```
{
    NSFilePath = "/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/08260B6A-4D65-48DF-ADD1-FFC8750081E8/Documents/abc";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. File exists\"";
}
```

I want to show the last line : "File exists", but how can i pick it out?

I tried:

```
localizedDescription
localizedFailureReason
localizedRecoverySuggestion
localizedRecoveryOptions
recoveryAttempter
```

Non of them show "File exists".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Finally, I follow code for perfect NSError print.
Thanks @jbat100 and @Peter Warbo, I add a little bit on them code:

```
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];
    NSString *errorString = [[userInfo objectForKey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey] localizedDescription];
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];
NSString *error = [userInfo objectForKey:@"NSUnderlyingError"];
NSLog(@"The error is: %@", error);
```

Comment: Yes, it press: "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. File exists\"" But, Can I pick out "The operation couldn't be completed. File exists" only ?

Comment: How about: `if([error code] == 17) NSLog("The operation couldn't be completed. File exists");`

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the [NSError documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nserror_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it has a `User info dictionary keys` section which has a constant defined as NSUnderlyingErrorKey (it also has a description for the keys).

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];
NSError *underlyingError = [userInfo objectForKey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey];
NSString *underlyingErrorDescription = [underlyingError localizedDescription];
```

Answer (score 1):

localizedRecoverySuggestion is very useful. 
You can get the JSON string from it:

```
NSString *JSON = [[error userInfo] valueForKey:NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey] ;

            NSError *aerror = nil;
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [JSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                 options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                   error: &aerror];
```

Comment: More compactly: `error.userInfo[NSUnderlyingErrorKey].localizedDescription;`